# How do I make c++ read \n inside of a character array?

Tags: c++

So, I am a beginner programmer in c++ and I started working on a short word search. I added a `bool` to the program where I can check if the word is either contained or is an exact word match.

The problem is I tried to do this `if text[textPos+1]='\n'` and of course it doesn't work. I've looked online through multiple solutions, but none of them have worked for me (examples: doing `\r` or using the ascii table numbers to check for an enter).

I'm going to attach my code to this post so people can see what I mean.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctype.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int wordLength = 0, textLength = 0, match = 0;
    char word[90];
    char text[1000];
    fstream textReader("data.in", ios::in);
    fstream wordReader("word.in", ios::in);
    while (textReader.get(text[textLength])) {
        textLength++;
    }
    while (!wordReader.eof()) {
        wordReader >> word[wordLength];
        wordLength++;
    }
    wordLength = wordLength - 1;
    textLength = textLength - 1;
    int spacesFound = 0;
    for (int textPos = 0; textPos < textLength; textPos++) {
        if (match == wordLength) {
                if (text[textPos + 1] == ' ') {
                spacesFound++;
                break;
            }else if (text[textPos + 1] == '\n'){
                spacesFound++;
                break;
            }
            else if (text[textPos + 1] != '\n') {
                match = 0;
                spacesFound = 0;
            }
        }
        else if (match == wordLength && spacesFound != 2) {
            spacesFound = 0;
        }
        if ((caseSensitive == true && word[0] == text[textPos]) {
            if (text[textPos - 1] == ' ') {
                spacesFound++;
            }
            match++;
            for (int wordPos = 1; wordPos < wordLength; wordPos++) {
                textPos++;
                if (word[wordPos] == text[textPos]) || tolower(word[wordPos]) == tolower(text[textPos]))) {
                    match++;
                }
                else {
                    match = 0;
                    spacesFound = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (match == wordLength && spacesFound == 2) {
        cout << "The word  " << word << " is part of the text";
    }else{
        cout<<"The word "<<word<<" is not part of the text";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So I was asked to provide a basic explanation of the code and to shorten it out, I'll explain the code and leave the shortened version above.

The code as it is right now reads the text out of a file called `data.in` and the word out of a file called `word.in`. After that it measures how many characters the word and the text have and then introduces an integer called `spacesfound`. Then goes through the text checking if the char from the word file is equal to the one from the text file. If they are its gonna add a match. If match is equal to the number of letters the word has then the word is part of the text. It checks if there are space before and after the word and here is where I encountered my problem:

I checked for space (' '), which worked for the most part, except if the program had a enter after the word, at which point I tried to check if the space in the array found right after the word in data.in is a `\n` which doesn't work.

Let's say we have the same sentence I gave earlier:

```
Doggo is a type of dog
but doggy is not.
```

After I know dog is the word I want if I check `text[textPos+1]= '\n'` it's not gonna work and I wanna know why.

Comment: You should shorten your code and provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: ^ Emphasis on ***minimal***!

Comment: I strongly suggest that you use std::stringstream to `tokenize` and then process each word. That's not the question, but you should use it.

Comment: `while (textReader.get(text[textLength]))` WAT? I think first explain what this code supposed to do (even before providing [mcve]). `short word search` is to vague explanation and code also is to messy to understand that.

Comment: @AndySukowski-Bang I don't know if I did that I just tried turning it into a minimal example taking only what I want answered from the program instead of the whole thing. Also explained it below.

Comment: @MarekR I just explained it below after turning it into what I think is a minimal reprducible example, that line there is supposed to read the text from a file called data.in as I explained above

Comment: Ok you have provided some explanation how code was written (I've did some editorial fixes to get rid of the scary wall of text), but my question was "what it suppose to do?", so in detail: what is your task? what is the input and what is expected output. For now I wonder why didn't you simply use stream operator `>>` which reads everything between white characters (words) and `std::string`.

Comment: This is how I understood your task: https://wandbox.org/permlink/p3vtBw20Xtoj2CYO

Comment: @MarekR well you got it about right but I don't understand what the program you've provided does, from what I understand it does exactly what I need my program to do. My program is supposed to take the word "dog" and look for it in data.in if it finds a letter that matches its gonna add one to the match counter, if the counter reaches the same number as the word's length then it will check for spaces before and after the word, so I made it check for ' ' and I wanted to make it check for "/n" too in case the word is at the end of a line. That's all I need.

Comment: I'm glad I help you get question unstuck :). Hopefully you've learn how to better state your questions in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, it seems like you want to read a word from "word.in" and then see if "data.in" contains that word.

If that's what you want to accomplish, you are overcomplicating things.
Using `>>` with strings already does the word separation you're looking for.
You also don't need to read the entire text at once - you can read it word for word.

Example:

```
#include <cctype>

std::string to_lower(std::string s)
{
    std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), [](char c){return std::tolower(c); });
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    std::string word;
    std::ifstream ws("word.in");
    ws >> word;
    word = to_lower(word);

    bool found = false;
    std::string candidate;
    std::ifstream text("data.in");
    while (text >> candidate && !found)
    {
        if (to_lower(candidate) == word)
        {
            found = true;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "The word " << word << " is " << (found ? "" : "not") << " part of the text.\n";
}
```

Using arrays:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

char* to_lower(char* s)
{
    int len = std::strlen(s);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        s[i] = std::tolower(s[i]);
    }
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    char word[90];
    std::ifstream ws("word.in");
    ws >> word;
    to_lower(word);

    bool found = false;
    char candidate[90];
    std::ifstream text("data.in");
    while (text >> candidate && !found)
    {
        if (!std::strcmp(to_lower(candidate), word))
        {
            found = true;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "The word " << word << " is " << (found ? "" : "not") << " part of the text.\n";
}
```

Comment: Well this is basically a thing I got to do from a guy who's teaching me c++ and he said I shall do it with what he basically thought me and I learned in school, basically he wanted me to do it with arrays... Also I have basic knowledge of most things but I don't think I can do it this way

Comment: You can use arrays instead of `std::string` (see edit), but it's not a very good idea to use arrays with inputs whose size you don't know beforehand.

Comment: I was told to use that exact number for the array actually... and keep my text short

Comment: Also sorry to bother you but as I said I'm a beginner and I have no clue what the part from char* to return s does

Comment: @Luca you can provide this link to your C++ teacher: ["Stop teaching C"](https://youtu.be/YnWhqhNdYyk) (I know title is clickbaity, but talk is great).

Comment: @MarekR I asked him personally to help me and just give me some stuff to keep me busy with while I develop my skills, since this is the language we are doing in school too, he isn't literally teaching me he is just giving me tips and sometimes exercises (like once a month). I've come here because I've been stuck on this thing for over 2 weeks now

Comment: @Luca OK, I rewrote the case-conversion function to a form you might recognize.

Comment: for some reason I got a whole bunch of compilation errors and idk if that might be on my part but that might be from me using an online compiler instead of a normal one.

Comment: You might be missing some header (and I might have left out a few "std::"s). Try the edit; it should be complete.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is really helpful! Although it has one last error and I really don't know what this one is: `main.cpp:21:25: error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘char*’ to ‘char [90]’` I'm sorry for bothering you again!

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood your trying to find the character `'\n'` inside an array, that doesn't exist, a string/char array has the last character `'\0'` so maybe try replacing `'\n'` with `'\0'` in the `if()` conditions.

Comment: This doesn't work I just tested it out. Thanks anyways!